# Como criar validação de dependência entre campos no CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validação

No CodeIgniter existe a possibilidade de criar regras (*rules*) de validação para cada campo do formulário, porém o que eu preciso é uma validação entre dois campos. Explico:

O formulário possui um campo chamado `url` que só é obrigatório caso a *flag* correspondente estiver selecionada.

Comment: Não sei se em Codeigniter consegues fazer isso, porque é uma validação do lado do Cliente (possivelmente até dá). Se não conseguires tentar fazer por javascript/jquery

Comment: Com javascript é mais fácil fazer e está proto até, mas é boa práticar ter uma validação no backend também.

Comment: Conforme o @LuisComS comentou, também acredito que o ideal seja ter validação de ambos os lados. No client-side pode evitar que um formulário seja submetido com erros, evitando processamento desnecessário no server-side; e no server-side, para evitar que um possível bug na validação client-side seja explorada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, mas vai ter que usar os validadores callback_XXX:

```
public function index(){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('flag', 'Flag', '');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'URL', 'callback_checaflag');
}

public function checaflag($url){
    if($this->input->post('flag')){
      return $this->form_validation->required('url');
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Neto apenas adicionei um codigo de validação que encontrei em [valid-url-format-checking-in-codeignite](http://www.zack-notes.net/joomzack15/blog-othermenu-28/codeigniter-cat/373-valid-url-format-checking-in-codeigniter.html):
`
    public function checaflag($url) {
        $pattern = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
    if($this->input->post('flag')){
          return (bool)preg_match($pattern, $url);//$this->form_validation->required('url');
        }
    }
`

Comment: É realmente uma pena o CI não ter uma rule para validar URL

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa @LuisComS, seria fazer algo como:

```
public function index(){
    // Se tal campo estiver marcado, adicionar a regra para validar a URL
    if($this->input->post('eu_aceito')){
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'URL', 'callback_validaurl');
    }
}

public function validaurl($url){
    // Colocar aqui funcao para vallidar $url e retornar TRUE ou FALSE
}
```